# How to customize a css for markdown + knitr in Rstudio?

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr

I want to change the default style sheet for the `KnitHTML` function in `RStudio 0.96.331`.

I follow the instructions in this [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/custom-css-for-html-generated-using-rstudio/).

First I copy past the original markdown.css from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/blob/master/inst/resources/markdown.css) .  As a test I change the first few lines from:

```
body, td {
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 8px;
}
```

to red background

```
body, td {
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: red;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 8px;
}
```

and save it as `mymd.css` in my working directory.  I then create a style.R file as follows:

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML =
  function(inputFile, outputFile) {     
    require(markdown)
    markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='mymd.css')  
  }
)
```

Finally, I source the style.R file by clicking source and then go back to the `.Rmd` file and knit it to HTML.  I get the red background, but the math is not compiled e.g. $\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK，MathJax service [was down yesterday](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mathjax-users/VXNq-LtszTE) due to the GoDaddy outage. Can you confirm the math problem was not due to that?

Comment: tried again and still no math rendering.  You can replicate it I'm sure.

Comment: @Fred OK, I can reproduce it. I think this is a bug of the `markdown` package, and you need to report it to the package author or RStudio developers.

Comment: Has this bug been addressed?

Comment: @StevieP I'm not sure if it has been fixed, and you can try the latest version (v0.7) on CRAN. Anyway, we are moving towards the rmarkdown package now: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

So I may have a work around for you, but it involves using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/):

Suppose your style sheet is called `style.css`

Source the following code:

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = function(inputFile, outputFile) {
        system(paste("pandoc -c style.css", shQuote(inputFile),
                     "-o", shQuote(outputFile)))
          }
        )
```

Comment: Just FYI, this has been made very easy with the rmarkdown package: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com

Comment: *edit* finally got it to work. As a note to future self/others: if Ubuntu's software center won't let you install a .deb, right click and try the deb package manager.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a new feature that was not available at the time the question was asked. However, there is a simple solution I found here:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style

In the preamble of your .Rmd, just write this:

```
---
title: "Your title"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: yourstylefile.css
---
```